#  Unsupported Configuration: Using the font Calibri-Bold in versions of Xcode prior to 4.2 may have unexpected results

Tags: iphone, ios5

i am using font Calibri-Bold in whole application but i get the warning in application

Unsupported Configuration: Using the font Calibri-Bold in versions of Xcode prior to 4.2 may have unexpected results

please provide help how to resolve this issue in application

i am using ios 5.0

thanks in advance

Comment: please provide any help related to this issue.